# Appending a list to another list replaces whitespaces with \xa0 in front of Integers

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a script to scrape data of the web. This creates lists to store the results of each page, which are then appended to one big list.
Everything is working fine and dandy until I try to do the final step by appending one list to the other. This is the code section in Question:

```
result = makeSearch(item)
#######################################################
#EVERYTHING IS STILL FINE WHEN YOU PRINT AT THIS POINT#
#######################################################
#printList(result)
##################################################
#APPENDING THE LIST TO THE LIST CREATES THE ERROR#
##################################################
adresses.append(result)
```

For example, this turns `"Brückstr. 29"` into `"Brückstr.\xa029"`. I tried to remove it with `string.replace('\\xa0', ' ')`, but to no avail. It doesn't do a thing.
I have a feeling that it has to do with the combination of numbers and characters, but that doesn't explain why it only happens when you try to append it to another list.

If you try to run my program, use `Aachen` or another German city for `"Enter location: "`.

This is the complete program:

```
import urllib.request
import time
import csv

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Performs a HTTP-'POST' request, passes it to BeautifulSoup and returns the result
def doRequest(request):
    requestResult = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requestResult, from_encoding='iso-8859-1')
    return soup

#Returns all the result links from the given search parameters
def getLinksFromSearch(location):
    database = []
    links_unsortiert = []

    #The search parameters
    params = {
    'subject': 'Taxi',
    'location': location,
    #'distance': '-1',
    #'execute': 'Suchen',
    #'suggest_choose': 'on',
    #'radial_check': 'on',
    }

    DATA = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
    DATA = DATA.encode('iso-8859-1')

    request = urllib.request.Request(
    "http://www.gelbeseiten.de/yp/search.yp?subject=Taxi&location=" + location,
    DATA)

    # adding charset parameter to the Content-Type header.
    request.add_header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8")
    request.add_header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0")

    #The search request 
    soup = doRequest(request)

    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        database.append(link.get('href'))

    for item in database:
        if item.startswith("http://adresse.gelbeseiten.de/"):
            links_unsortiert.append(item)

    links = list(set(links_unsortiert))

    return links

#Performs a search on the link results
def searchOnLinks(links):
    adresses = []
    i = 1
    j = len(links)
    print("Gathering information, please wait...")
    for item in links:
        print("(" , i , "/" , j , ") Making request...")
        result = makeSearch(item)
        ########################################
        #EVERYTHING IS STILL FINE AT THIS POINT#
        ########################################
        printList(result)
        ##################################################
        #APPENDING THE LIST TO THE LIST CREATES THE ERROR#
        ##################################################
        adresses.append(result)
        for elem in adresses:
            for element in elem:
                element = element.replace('\xa0', ' ')
        i = i + 1
        time.sleep(0.3)
    print("All done.")
    return adresses

def makeSearch(link):
    request = urllib.request.Request(link)
    #Adding charset parameter to the Content-Type header.
    request.add_header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8")
    request.add_header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0")

    #The search request 
    soup = doRequest(request)

    name = ''
    strasse = ''
    plz = ''
    stadt = ''
    telefon = ''
    mail = ''
    url = ''

    data = [
           #'Name',
           #'Straße',
           #'PLZ',
           #'Stadt',
           #'Telefon',
           #'E-Mail',
           #'Homepage'
            ]

    try:
        fieldValue = soup.find(itemprop="name")
        name = fieldValue.next_element
        data.append(name)
    except AttributeError:
        print("Name not found!")
    try:
        fieldValue = soup.find(itemprop="streetAddress")
        strasse = fieldValue.next_element
        data.append(strasse)
    except AttributeError:
        print("Street not found!")

    try:
        fieldValue = soup.find(itemprop="postalCode")
        plz = fieldValue.next_element
        data.append(plz)
    except AttributeError:
        print("Zipcode not found!")

    try:
        fieldValue = soup.find(itemprop="addressLocality")
        stadt = fieldValue.next_element
        data.append(stadt)
    except AttributeError:
        print("City not found!")

    return data

def printList(liste):
    for element in liste:
        print(element)

#The main input/output function
def inputOutput():
    location = []

    while True:
        location = input("Enter location: ")
        try:
            links = getLinksFromSearch(location)
            break
        except urllib.error.HTTPError:
            print("Error! Input raised an HTTP-Exception. Please enter valid input.")


    #Checks if the search yielded any results
    if len(links) > 0:
        print("The search returned", len(links), "result(s).")
        print('To proceed, enter "go".')
        localVar = input('To do a new search, enter any key: ')
        if localVar == 'go':
            data = searchOnLinks(links)
            printList(data)
            saveData = input('Enter "save" if you want to save: ')
            if saveData == 'save':
                file_name = input("Save as: ")
                print("Writing to file...")
                with open(file_name + '.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
                    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
                    a.writerows(data)
            else:
                return
        else:
            return
    else:
        print("The search returned no results.")

#Program entry point
def main():
    while True:
        inputOutput()
        inputVar = input('If you want to run the application again, enter "y". To exit, enter any key: ')
        if inputVar != 'y':
            break

main()
```

Comment: `'\xa0'` is a [non-break space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm) which sounds completely appropriate when a regular space might wrap and wreck your table layout.

Comment: But why does it show up when I append one list to another? I wrote a similar program in the past where I did the same with similar strings with chars and numbers and this did not happen.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that when I save the Data to a .csv-file, the whitespaces are shown properly, so nevermind then.